# How to add days (in float) to a pandas Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, timestamp

I want to create a DataFrame that has a DateTime column and after the initial date I want to increment the number of days. The rule to add new dates is that I need to add 1.01 times the previous increment.

**This is what current DataFrame (named df) looks like:**

```
            last_time
0 2020-05-01 22:40:00
```

**This is what I want it to look like:** (initial increment in this example is 13 but that's not important)

```
  last_time

0 2020-05-01 22:40:00

1 2020-05-14 22:40:00

2 2020-05-28 1:47:12

3 2020-06-10 8:03:28
```

*As you can see each time the increment is 1.01 times the previous increment*.

**This is the code that I tried** but after running it and getting an error, I got to know that in DateOffset we can only use int, so my question is how do we use some simple function like DateOffset but be able to use float instead or perhaps any other way to achieve the end result.

```
for i in range(11):
    s = df.iloc[i]["last_time"] + pd.DateOffset(13*1.01**i,)
    df = df.append({"last_time": s}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You have to convert your time in days to the appropriate units for a `timedelta`.

Comment: why do you even have a dataframe? this seems strange use case for a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be changed with [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
for i in range(11):
    s = df.iloc[i]["last_time"] + pd.Timedelta(13*1.01**i, unit='d')
    df = df.append({"last_time": s}, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
                       last_time
0  2020-05-01 22:40:00.000000000
1  2020-05-14 22:40:00.000000000
2  2020-05-28 01:47:12.000000000
3  2020-06-10 08:03:28.319999999
4  2020-06-23 17:30:42.403199999
5  2020-07-07 06:10:48.827231999
6  2020-07-20 22:05:43.315478399
7  2020-08-03 17:17:22.748649599
8  2020-08-17 15:47:45.176102399
9  2020-08-31 17:38:49.827849599
10 2020-09-14 22:52:37.126137599
11 2020-09-29 07:31:08.697369599
```